# Modifying inner reader in a transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, reader-monad

I'm pulling together code from a number of different places, and I'm trying to deal with the following:

## Problem

I have a transformer stack with the following simplified type:

```
action :: m (ReaderT r IO) a
```

and I'm trying to use the action in the context of a different stack, which has a different reader environment:

```
desired :: m (ReaderT r' IO) a
```

I can of course provide

```
f :: r' -> r
```

### Example

```
things :: m (ReaderT r' IO) ()
things = do
   -- ... some stuff

   -- <want to use action here>
   action :: m (ReaderT r IO) a -- broken

    -- ... more stuff
   pure ()
```

### What I've considered

```
withReaderT :: (r' -> r) -> ReaderT r m a -> ReaderT r' m a
```

This has the problem that ReaderT is the outer monad, whilst I want to use it on an inner one.

I've also considered that this might be related to MonadBase or MonadTransControl, but I'm not familiar with their workings.

Comment: Have you seen https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html? If you provide `ReaderT r m a -> ReaderT r' m a`, `hoist` from `MFunctor` can do what you want.

Comment: Whether you can do this also depends on `m`.  For example this is not possible with `ContT`.

Comment: Indeed. Checkout the instances for `MFunctor` for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to write a function with signature:

```
changeReaderT :: (MonadTrans m)
                 => (r -> r') 
                 -> m (ReaderT r IO) a 
                 -> m (ReaderT r' IO) a
```

the issue being that the only operation possible, in general, on the second argument is lifting it to `t (m (ReaderT r IO)) a` for some monad transformer `t`, which doesn't buy you anything.

That is, the `MonadTrans m` constraint alone doesn't provide enough structure to do what you want.  You either need `m` to be an instance of a typeclass like `MFunctor` in the `mmorph` package that allows you to modify an inner layer of the monad stack in a general way by providing a function like:

```
hoist :: Monad m => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b
```

(which is what @Juan Pablo Santos was saying), or else you need an ability to dig into the structure of your `m` monad transformer to partially run and rebuild it (which will be transformer-specific).

The first approach (using `hoist` from the `mmorph` package) will be most convenient if your `m` is already made up of transformers supported by the `mmorph` package.  For example, the following typechecks, and you don't have to write any instances:

```
type M n = MaybeT (StateT String n)

action :: M (ReaderT Double IO) a
action = undefined

f :: Int -> Double
f = fromIntegral

desired :: M (ReaderT Int IO) a
desired = (hoist $ hoist $ withReaderT fromIntegral) action
```

You'll need a `hoist` for each layer in `M`.

The second approach avoids `hoist` and requisite `MFunctor` instances but requires tailoring to your specific `M`.  For the above type , it looks something like:

```
desired' :: M (ReaderT Int IO) a
desired' = MaybeT $ StateT $ \s ->
  (withReaderT fromIntegral . flip runStateT s . runMaybeT) action
```

You basically need to run the monad down to the `ReaderT` layer and then rebuild it back up, treating layers like `StateT` with care.  This is exactly what the `MFunctor` instances in `mmorph` are doing automatically.